How to assign a returned value of @Composable function to a property in class?
issue
details
I want to assign the initial value of property of MutableStateFlow type in object in Android.
But the initial value is a returned value of @Composable function, so it is NOT allowed to use the assignment operator to assign it. Otherwise, it will get a compiler error.
A wrong example.
object MealsOptionRepository {
    private val _selectedDataFlow: MutableStateFlow<MealsOptionVO> = MutableStateFlow(fetchData()[0])

...

    @Composable
    fun fetchData(): List<MealsOptionVO> {
        return listOf(
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.breakfast_leading_icon,
                stringResource(R.string.breakfast),
                stringResource(R.string.breakfast_name),
            ),
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.lunch_leading_icon,
                stringResource(R.string.lunch),
                stringResource(R.string.lunch_name),
            ),
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.dinner_leading_icon,
                stringResource(R.string.dinner),
                stringResource(R.string.dinner_name),
            ),
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.supper_leading_icon,
                stringResource(R.string.supper),
                stringResource(R.string.supper_name),
            ),
        )
    }

    // a method that set _selectedDataFlow.value to newData atomically 
    @Composable
    fun setSelectedData(newData:MealsOptionVO){
        _selectedDataFlow.update { newData }
    }
}

where MealsOptionVO is data class defined as follows.
data class MealsOptionVO(
    val innerIconId : Int,
    val name : String, // actual name
    val text : String, // alias name
)

It will throw a compiler error
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
I want to initialize the property _selectedDataFlow once, and thus I can invoke fetchData method once (and I can't invoke it in getter of property _selectedDataFlow.
And for maintenability, I don't want to initialize the property _selectedDataFlow with a dummy MealsOptionVO instance (such as private val _selectedDataFlow: MutableStateFlow<MealsOptionVO> = MutableStateFlow(1,"","") ), then invoke @Composable fetchData method at startup of execution.
(such as in
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HealthHelperTheme {
                MealsOptionRepository.setSelectedData(MealsOptionRepository.fetchData()[0])
                Main()
            }
        }
    }
}

)
How can I do?
Appreciation
Any reply or tip of this issue will be appreciated.
What did I try?

ask the teacher before I post this issue a few minutes ago.

What was I expecting?

solve this problem.


Your code is badly architected.  Composable functions should never be returning a value, and should not be calculating data.  Your data should already have been in your state object, and your composable should only be drawing your UI based on that state.  If your Composable function does anything else, it's doing too much.  Architect your data and state correctly and there's no problem.

Before I post this issue, the teacher give me a solution.
solution
Always use id in data class, when one has to access it, find the value by the id
In my example, I can solve this issue by these following steps.

In MealsOptionVO data class, store its id of source. Thus, I have to set its property to Int. As follows.

data class MealsOptionVO(
    @DrawableRes val iconResId: Int,
    @StringRes val nameResId: Int,
    @StringRes val textResId: Int,
)





Then I refactor some method as follows.
Removing the stringResource built-in method (since it can be used in @Composable function.
And then I can remove @Composable annotation to fetchData method.
Complete code snippets as follows.
fetchData method
fun fetchData(): List<MealsOptionVO> {
        return listOf(
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.breakfast_leading_icon,
                R.string.breakfast,
                R.string.breakfast_name,
            ),
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.lunch_leading_icon,
                R.string.lunch,
                R.string.lunch_name,
            ),
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.dinner_leading_icon,
                R.string.dinner,
                R.string.dinner_name,
            ),
            MealsOptionVO(
                R.drawable.supper_leading_icon,
                R.string.supper,
                R.string.supper_name,
            ),
        )

setSelectedData method
fun setSelectedData(newData:MealsOptionVO){
   _selectedDataFlow.update { newData }
}


Take the value of id of source only when one has to access the value.

In my example, to access a String from R.string.lunch, use stringResource(fetchData()[1].nameResId)
(before fix this issue, I write fetchData()[1].nameResId.)

You can also create function, that will fetch all resources by passing context as argument. This will help, for example, if you can't change data class. You can also create adapter class that will hold ids and then transform it to your data by using some kind of extension function
